# `Rosmake`don't create a executable

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a problem with Rosmake not creating a executable, which make no sense why it doesn't..

here is the [output](http://pastebin.com/pgfwkCHs) from `rosmake`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203428/%60rosmake%60don%27t-create-a-executable../) by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2015-02-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2015-02-19**:
Your pastebin link doesn't work.

**Comment by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) on 2015-02-19**:
link fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Used roscreate-pkg instead of catkin_create_pkg..
I think it must have something with my dependencies.

---

Originally posted by [215](https://answers.ros.org/users/21533/215/) with karma: 156 on 2015-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1